# Arduino to MySQL via phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

EDIT: 22 Aug 2015 @ 22:44z

Hi all,

My "post" and "display" PHPs work.  I've checked both of them thoroughly.  I am almost certain that the fault is in the code below, I just don't know where.

The questions is "why can't the arduino/wifishield connect to a MySQL database hosted by NetSol managed by phpmyadmin?" I have the DB IP address, pass, username, etc. baked into the PHPs.

Here is the C code that I'm using:

```
void postData() {
if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
Serial.println("connecting...");
client.println("POST /insert_mysql.php HTTP/1.1")
//I've verified this PHP connects to the DB via the IP address
client.println("Host: www.<my_website>.com"); //hosted by NetSol
client.println("User-Agent: Arduino/1.0"); //should this be 2.0?
client.println("Connection: close");
client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;");
client.print("Content-Length: ");
client.println(yourdata.length());
client.println();
client.println(yourdata);
} 
else {
Serial.println("Connection failed");
Serial.println("Disconnecting.");
client.stop();
}
}
```

Comment: In the `postData` function I see a web request to a script named `insert_mysql.php` . You would need to code that script to make it accept the data and to store it in the MySQL database table .

Comment: It's impossible to help you until we get more information. The process must look like this: Arduino program (C) -> Server script (PHP) -> MySQL.

Comment: We want to see the portion of your C file, that sends the data and PHP script, that accepts the data from Arduino and inserts it into the database.

Comment: In order to keep this apples:apples, I'll include the sketch author's PHP.  I've modified my version with my specifics, but that's it.

Here's the matching "insert_mysql.php":
[link]https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ericbenwa/POST-Arduino-Data-Wireless/master/insert_mysql.php[/link]

I can post additional detail when I get home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a very simple resolution...

1.) WiFi Shield needed a firmware upgrade to 1.1.0

2.) The shield's antenna is weak so I had to get a better signal